# Android httpClient Server Authentication

Tags: android, http, authentication

Im making an android application which retrieves data from a web page with encoded JSON. At the moment when i go to the page in a web browser it asks me for a Server Authentication   where i enter my username and password. How do i make it so when i do a httpPost; It will send a Username and password with it so i can access the page.

Its this kind of Authentification http://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/web-server-authentication-dialogue-box.png

How do i do this? Here's my code:

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        try {
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: do you want to username and password to server with url..isn't it?

Comment: its this kind of server username and pass http://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/web-server-authentication-dialogue-box.png

Answer (score 0):

You can send your user name and password like this :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(your_username_key_string, your_username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(your_password_key_string, your_password));            

HttpPost oHttpPost = new HttpPost(your_server_url);
oHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Comment: Whats the difference between your_username_key_string and your_username? im not sure what the first one is?

Comment: Though NameValuePair is a key-value pair then your_username_key_string  is key in string format and your_username is the value in string format of this key which you you want to post

Answer (score 0):

Ok...so you can pass it with:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

String url = "yoururl"+"username="+YourUsername+"password="+Your Paasword;

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    try {
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your parameters to the post:

```
final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));  
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

This is assuming that your login form looks like:

```
input type="text" name="username"
input type="password" name="password"
```

Comment: Its a server username and password like this http://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/web-server-authentication-dialogue-box.png